# Is it good to have foregin key reference to all the tables (indirect references)?

Tags: database, schema

Its a simple scenario like say :

### University Table

```
UNIV_IDN         Name
1                UT
```

### University Campus Table

```
CAMPUS_IDN  Name
1           UT Austin
2           UT Arlington
```

### Event Registration Table

```
EVENT_IDN  CAMPUS_IDN  UNIV_IDN
1          2           1
2          1           1
```

Event at any point of time is concerned with CAMPUS_IDN , but not with UNIV_IDN directly . 
Although it makes sense , is it required to have UNIV_IDN in the Event Registration Table or should it ONLY have CAMPUS_IDN which in terms can get the UNIV_IDN ? How are DB's usually designed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need univ_idn column in university campus table:

```
CAMPUS_IDN  Name          Univ_ID
1           UT Austin     1
2           UT Arlington  1
```

Then your event registration table doesn't need univ_id column: you can find out the university from the campus table.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you have denormalized data in event (which is bad)

Comment: Correct both the example and denomarlized was what I was thinking about.